# How to verify the changes made in ant build file without running the whole build again?

Tags: java, ant

Is there any way by which i can see any errors in build.xml file without running the build again? i mean is there any tool for that?

Comment: Unfortunately ant's build.xml doesn't have any schema or DTD that determines what's right or wrong...

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to use any IDE (like Eclipse for Java EE Developers edition), they include support for editing of ant build files, including code completion, syntactical error detection etc.

Answer (score 3):

Syntactic parsing of build.xml happens during start of ant. You can just add "empty" ant task that does nothing and run it to validate your build.xml. Candidate for such empty task is task which just prints out targets declared inside build.xml, i.e., "usage help page".

Besides this kind of validation, you can't be 100% sure your build.xml is correct without actually running build process.